# Angular2: how to chain ngModel with two-way bound variable of other component?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel, two-way-binding

I have a `main-component` which passes a variable to another component `sub-component` via custom two-way binding. The passed variable is used for an input tag via `ngModel`.

These two variables are currently not in sync. How can I chain those two variables?

main.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-component',
  templateUrl: './main-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-component.component.css']
})
export class MainComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  private you: any = {};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.you.name = "Name";
  }
}
```

main.component.html

```
<div>
  This is the main component.
  you.name = {{you.name}}
  <br>
  <app-sub-component [(variable)]="you.name"></app-sub-component>
</div>
```

sub.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, Output, EventEmitter, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub-component',
  templateUrl: './sub-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub-component.component.css']
})
export class SubComponentComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() variable: any;

  @Output() variableChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
  }
}
```

sub.component.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="variable">

Variable = {{variable}}
```

Given above configuration,
I want the variable `you.name` in the main component and the variable `variable` in the sub-component to be in sync.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use  `onModelChange()` on the child. Here is an example:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-di6px5?file=app/form.component.ts)

**child:**

```
  @Input() name;
  @Input() surname;
  @Input() age;

  @Output() nameChange = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() surnameChange = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() ageChange = new EventEmitter();


  onModelChange(event, type) { 
    this[`${type}Change`].emit(event); //this line was optimised by yurzui
  }
```

**parent**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <child [(name)]="name" [(surname)]="surname" [(age)]="age"></child>
      <br><br>
      Name :{{name}} 
      <br>
      Surname: {{surname}} 
      <br>
      Age: {{age}} 
      <br>
      <button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  name:string;
  surname:string;
  age:number;


  reset(){
    this.name = "";
    this.surname = "";
    this.age = 18;
  } 

  ngOnInit(){
    this.reset();
  }

}
```

Comment: Or `this[`${type}Change`].emit(event);` to reduce the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-di6px5?file=app/form.component.ts